# Can the MSAL API be used with B2C only - or B2B application too?

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

We're considering to use Azure AD B2B OR B2C for SSO service. We will not be using Azure B2B built-in SSO login page OR B2C custom-policies based login page. We've our own custom login JSP page that we plan to use MSAL Graph APIs for calling Azure AD authentication services.

Questions:

1. Is this MSAL APIs applicable to B2C only, or can we use this with B2B tenant application as well? All the documents and guidance that I can take as an example uses B2C tenant app only.
2. If I am using MSAL OAuth 2.0 authentication services for my custom login page, I assume we don't need to rely on SAML SSO configuration. Or would it be possible to use mix of these services (i.e. SAML for basic login authentication, MSAL OAuth2.0 calls for self service account registration)?

I appreciate if anyone can shed some light on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

B2B and B2C serve two different purposes. B2B is meant for you to use to invite external federated users to your directory using their own credentials whereby you can assign them access directly to your resources. On the other hand, B2C is a separate directory where you allow users to register, optionally using their own credentials from federated providers as well. If your aim is to SSO to a local AzureAD protected resource, then clearly you're going to have to tell that resource to use the B2C directory as an IdP as well. Hence, B2B is much simpler for SSO, but a big differentiator is scale. If you plan to invite a massive number of users, then this it is not a good idea to user B2B.

MSAL uses standard protocols such as OAuth 2.0 and OIDC to authenticate directly to any supported IdP, including Azure AD or Azure AD B2C. Being a guest user or not has no bearing on that process. It is also important to mention that B2C does require either a User Flow or a Custom Policy to function.

So to answer your questions to the best of my ability:

1- MSAL libraries work similarly for both Azure AD and Azure AD B2C. There may be some configuration differences in case of B2C to supply additional information regarding the policy name, etc. But they work all the same.

2- MSAL itself does not support SAML authentication. For that you'll need a library which can perform SAML authentication. While Azure AD supports SAML natively, Azure AD B2C requires you to setup a custom policy to configure SAML authentication.

Comment: Thanks Hazen, this helps a lot. I am trying to use the custom login page designed in JSP for OKTA and Azure SSO(For some clients  we need to redirect to OKTA for others Azure SSO). The existing .jsp custom login page integrated with OKTA SSO as it has the provision to specify JSP custom login page whereas in Azure AD B"B / B2C SSO, I don't see any option to specify this. The only option is to provide .html and .css custom file on page layout section. I am thinking to call Graph API from OKTA custom login page by acquiring MSAL OAUTH token. Any thoughts on this please? Thanks.

Comment: My advice is to customize your JSP to use MSAL for Java, For example, when user clicks (Login with Azure) they shall be redirected to an Azure provided login page which you can brand accordingly, then after login is complete users shall be redirected back to your website where MSAL logic will kick in to provide you with the required claims and token. This will work similarly for both Azure AD or Azure AD B2C, you'll just have to provide slightly different config. A sample can be found here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-java-webapp

Comment: Thanks Hazem, I understand this approach (i.e. our own jsp to use MSAL for Java to get oauth authentication tokens and use Graph API to play with Azure AD user accounts) DOES NOT require our web application to be registered on Azure AD B2B / B2C with SAML registration custom-policies user flows. Isn't it? thanks again.